# Can I add a WordPress blog as a "news" section to my existing website?

Tags: html, wordpress, web, content-management-system

I have created a website and would like to create a "news" section on it.
But I'm going to use this website with a friend that doesn't know html and I thought maybe it's easier to edit that news section with a content management system like WordPress.
So I would like to integrate WordPress just for that "news" section like a blog entry so that my friend can edit or add new posts to this section in WordPress.
I'm a total beginner in WordPress, so I'd like to get detailed help from you.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress was ment for developing blogs, but with the years it evolved to much more. So yes, you can add news as category, after that you can 'attach' post to that category, and display post from only this category on a page. Spend some time on reading about categories and tags in Wordpress. Chosing Wordpress for a blog is a big YES!

Comment: Could you tell me how to do this? I can not find any tutorial to this specific topic.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be wordpress and do you know any PHP?

Because I just recently stumbled upon [bludit](https://www.bludit.com) -> a very easy to use flat file cms that might be perfect for your situation.

I think that Bludit is a lot easier to understand and very straight forward to implement into an existing html website. (Compared to WP)

Edit:

Here an example snippet of a bludit blog post list:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">

            <!-- Content -->
           <!-- loop through the pages and create a post-preview div with a link to the blog post detail page -->
            <?php foreach ($content as $page): ?>

                <div class="post-preview">
                    <a href="<?php echo $page->permalink() ?>">
                        <h2 class="post-title"><?php echo $page->title() ?></h2>
                        <h3 class="post-subtitle"><?php echo $page->description() ?></h3>
                    </a>
                    <p class="post-meta"><?php echo $language->get('Posted by').' '.$page->user('username').' - '.$page->date() ?></p>
                </div>
                <hr>

            <?php endforeach ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here an example snippet of the blog post detail page:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
    <!-- display the content of the post -->
    <?php echo $page->content() ?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The above examples are taken from the [bludit clean blog theme github repo](https://github.com/bludit-themes/clean-blog/blob/master/php/page.php)

Comment: I have small knowledge about PHP yet.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21172595)

Comment: Sorry for all the unnecessary edits everyone! I'm still learning how to use stack overflow. Thanks for the help Al Foиce ѫ & Matthew Groves, i tried to be more elaborate and I added examples of how the asker could achieve what he's trying to do. Is that better, @Matthew Groves?

Comment: Hi @Johnny, I think your input is valuable, but mainly as a comment and not an answer. Hip is asking specifically for WordPress help. So while bludit and your example might be useful, it doesn't answer the question. Imagine it wasn't a tech question. Let's say it was "How much flour should I use in a cake". Instead of answering "2 cups", your answer is more like "You should make donuts instead!" Which, hey, I like donuts better too, but it should be a comment here on SO and not an answer. Hope that helps, thank you for contributing!

Comment: Hi @MatthewGroves,
Thank you very much for your explanation! Makes total sense now :P should I delete my answer and add it as comment or can I keep it like this?

Comment: I'd recommend deleting as an answer and adding a comment. I also voted to close the question, as it's too broad and opinion-based for Stack Overflow anyway.

Comment: @MatthewGroves, will do as soon as I have my 50 reputation.